# How to determine the least degree the function can have? (Highschool Algebra 2)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I've got stuck on the question asking, "Estimate the coordinates of each turning point and state whether each corresponds to a local maximum or a local minimum. Then estimate all real zeros and determine the least degree the function can have."

The question provided the graph as following,

[image: The provided graph.]

Anyhow, I've got the local min&max and zeros.

Local MIN (2,-2)

Local MAX (1,0) & (3,0)

Zero {1,3}

However, I've got confused and stuck at getting least degree. Slader said the right answer was 4th degree because it intersect x-axis 4 times which I don't get.

Anyhow, I appreciate your help. Please make it highschoolish as possible. Thanks.

(I tried searching but everything was too advanced.)

Comment: Yes. it "intersects the x-axis four times", in a sense, because  1 and 3 are "double roots"- (1, 0) and (3, 0) are turning points- the graph turns back there rather than crossing the x-axis.

Answer (score 2):

While circumventing calculus (it can kill the problem), here's what we can say: the minimal degree of a polynomial given its graph is the number of turning points plus one. It's just how things are. You can't quite count the number of roots because of multiplicity - this means roots may repeat.

Comment: Multiplicity would only increase the degree. You can always say that if it crosses the axis four times then the degree is at the very least $4$.

Comment: The fundamental theorem of algebra is enough to get "at least $4$". In fact, we can sometimes use the fundamental theorem of algebra to establish more than that obtained by simply counting turning points. In what follows, let $f(x)$ the the function. Since the graph of $y=f(x)$ intersects the horizontal line $y=-1$ in $4$ places, it follows that $f(x) + 1$ has degree at least $4,$ and hence $f(x)$ has degree at least $4.$ Can we do better? That is, can we show it must have degree greater than $5,$ or even better, can we show it must have degree greater than $6,$ etc.? **(continued)**

Comment: Trying/visualizing nonvertical lines, it is easy to see that the graph of $y=f(x)$ intersects any given nonvertical line in at most $4$ places, so it follows that for any given real numbers $a,b$ we have that $f(x)-ax-b$ has degree at least $4,$ and hence $f(x)$ has degree at least $4$ (since $f(x)$ obviously has degree greater than $1,$ otherwise its graph would be a line). Trying parabolas, it is easy to see that the graph of $y=f(x)$ intersects any given parabola (with a vertical axis) in at most $4$ places, **(continued)**

Comment: so it follows that for any given real numbers $a,b,c$ we have that $f(x)-ax^2-bx-c$ has degree at least $4,$ and hence $f(x)$ has degree at least $4$ (since $f(x)$ obviously has degree greater than $2,$ otherwise its graph would be a line or a parabola). This doesn't prove we CAN'T improve "at least $4$" to "at least $5$", but it does eliminate some of the simple ways one can argue that "at least $4$" (obtained by turning points, or by number of times the graph of the given function crosses the $x$-axis) can be improved/strengthened. **(continued)**

Comment: FYI, this question was recently bumped to the main page by an edit, which is why, 6 years after you posted your answer, I'm just now seeing your answer and making this (longish) comment.